# Responsive plugin vs universal app in ext js

Tags: extjs, responsive-design, sencha-touch

We have a web application built using classic toolkit of ext js. We want to make this application available to users from  mobile. We hae two options. 1.Either use responsive plugin and make all the components responsive for the various mobiles. 2. Build a universal application with modern toolkit for mobile. As I am very new to the UI development, I am not able to evaluate these appraoches. Any help would on making this choice will be appreciated

More specifically, I am looking at answers to these questions.

- would you  be able to make all the components responsive just be using the responsive plugin?
- If we go ahead with responsive plugin, would it possible to add new components to the mobile
- Will adding the responsive plugin have any impact on performance
- Considering that we want the application to provide a good user experience to users over desktop and mobile, is the universal design the right path to follow.
- What are the important aspects to consider if we are going for a universal application. Would it have an impact on the performance of the classic application.
- what are the aspects to consider in terms of scalability of the design and which approach supports acalability

Answer (score 1):

Ext.plugin.Responsive will only allow you to add different configurations for components depending on the devicetype/resolution of the User Agent. It will not make things touch friendly or add alternative UIs for mobile.

1. With that said, the plugin can be applied to all components in ExtJS classic, but can only manipulate properties/configs that have a setter function.
2. The responsive plugin cannot add or remove any components, but you can of course add components that are not visible by default on Desktop or mobile by setting the visible property in the responsiveConfiguration
3. There's more code that needs to be transferred, but the actual "media queries" shouldn't have any measurable impact on performance. Obviously all the changes to the defaults you add in responsiveConfiguration is applied afterwards and depending on the complexity takes some time.
4. The Classic Toolkit of ExtJS was built with only Computers with mouse and keyboard in mind. All controls are optimized for either keyboard or mouse interaction and might seem very small on handheld devices. The modern toolkit on the other hand stems from Sencha Touch which was always designed as a mobile first approach. UI elements are bigger and make use of features only available on touch devices or add additional visual controls that would otherwise only be available on the computer hardware.
   The Modern toolkit works and looks good on desktop computers, though. So unless you have any legacy stuff that can't be migrated to modern or want to migrate only parts of your application I'd completely drop the classic stuff and focus on the modern UI.
5. If you provide both modern and classic version of your application, neither should have any performance impact on the other. You'll have a lot of development overhead, though, as you need to maintain both UI versions seperately.
6. No idea what you mean with that point. Scalability in terms of screen size? - Modern is the way to go for that. The classic UI doesn't look too good if resized.
   Or did you mean scalability in terms of adding more components? - As the modern UI components take up more screen space than their classic counterparts, I guess classic scales better.
   When it comes to growing complexity and maintaining a 2 track app with both a classic and modern UI, that's pretty much a nightmare as you'll have to duplicate lots of stuff in both UI versions and have to do the debugging in both UI versions.
   That obviously depends on the complexity of your UI and less on the complexity of the app itself. If it's worth maintaining both UI versions is something you'll have to evaluate on a case by case basis. There's no general rule to when it makes sense and when to better drop one UI version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By scalability, I meant the ease of adding new components for web and mobile. Also, from what I researched, although modern tool kit should support both desktop and browsers, the version of ext js we use,6.2, doesn't support. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Apparently if you create a universal app with both classic and modern toolkit, Desktop browsers will always see the classic version unless you append ?modern to the url or fake the user agent to look like a mobile.

Comment: However if you only have a Modern toolkit version of your app, it will display that on desktop browsers as well.
I've got no idea how to update an old app to that format by hand or with the sencha tool, though.
If you run `sencha generate app --modern` you should end up with an empty app that only contains the modern framework instead of both.